# Python 3.x using argparse calculate the annual interest and initial down payment?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having some issues writing a python script for a 3.x version. I need to write a python in where can i calculates the annual interest for a requested principal. There will be a default interest rate if no credit information is provided and initial down payment may be paid. I started but I'm getting errors.

Thanks

```
import sys
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="extracting command-line para")

parser.add_argument(
  help = 'Total Request',
  nargs='+',
  dest = 'TotalRequest',
  default = [],
  type = str
)

parser.add_argument(
  '-c',
  '--credit',
   help = 'Calc interest rate',
   dest = 'credit',
   default = '650',
   type = int)

parser.add_argument(
  help = 'List of principals',
  nargs='+',
  dest = 'principal',
  default = [],
  type = str
)

arg = parser.parse_args()

if arg.credit >= 700:
  rate = 4.5
elif arg.credit >= 600 and arg.credit < 700:
  rate = 5.0
else:
  rate = 6.0

sum = 0
for p in arg.principal:
  sum = sum + int(p)

interest = sum * rate / 100

print ("Total Request: ", sum)
print ("Down payment: ",)
print ("Principal: ", sum)
print ("Interest rate: ", rate)
print ("Annual interest: ", interest)
```

Comment: Can you include the specific error messages you're getting in your question?

Comment: Hi xgord, Sure, eventually of the error i believe my script is not well done. But of the many errors is sum = default + int(p) name error = name 'default' is not defined. Also when i run it i can't get the down payment working.

Answer (score 0):

When you set a default value as you do here:

```
parser.add_argument(
  help = 'List of principals',
  nargs='+',
  dest = 'principal',
  default = [],
  type = str
)
```

This is not actually assigning a default variable but instead it is a parameter to the add_argument function, which assigns a default value to the argument.  So for the above example your principal value will be

```
principal = []
```

With the above in mind when you try to access the default variable, it is unknown.

```
for p in arg.principal:
  sum = default + int(p)
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, I fixed it according to your response but now i can't get a down payment. I delete some part of my down payment script but now i didn't get anything as you can see up there. Did you run the script in your machine?

Comment: @Mike Why did you remove the down payment portion of the script?

Comment: Hi brian,because i fixed  the errors that i had but still having issues with the downpayment.

Comment: @Mike did you provide input to the script?  What is the value of arg.principal?

Comment: Well yes i did. If you run the script you'll see that down-payment is empty i can't add a value to down-payment also the value of arg.principal is Ok. I just need to add a new one parser.add_argument(
  help = 'Down Payment',
  nargs='+',
  dest = 'Down Payment',
  default = [],
  type = str

Comment: @Mike I don't know if you can put Spaces in the dest field value.  I'd suggest looking at the function documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument

Comment: no clue so far. there is a way that you can provide me the script in order to get a downpayment. I'm just missing that part i can get the interest rate but now i need to add the downpayment and get a result. Thanks

Comment: @Mike if this answer helped you reach your answer please mark it as accepted as a sign to others that no further action is necessary.